# Visual Studio 2017 Movierental date settings

Tags: php, html, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have a movierental application it is based on like a ticket reservation on a cinema
But it requires a certain scenario

"Example
Venom: Let there be carnage
To be released on June 25 2021"

My goal is to make it unable to "reserve a ticket reservation before the movie release date

Here are my codes.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Schedule, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="date" name="Schedule" required />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In POST Action, you can compare the date.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel My)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (My.Schedule > DateTime.Today)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Movie has not released yet.");
            return View();
        }
        //Otherwise do further process here
    }
    return View();
}
```